# How can I force my SharePoint AjaxSmartPart to use the smaller "Release" mode javascript?

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, wss-3.0, smartpart

I use `ReturnOfSmartPart` on `WSS3` to display a `ASCX` in `Sharepoint` as a web part. This works beautifully.

The only problem is that the `AjaxSmartPart` seems to be using the Debug mode javascript (the scripts are close to 1MB!)

How can I ensure that the `AjaxSmartPart` only uses the `Release` mode java scripts?

**Note:**

- I have Published my `ASCX` in Release
  mode.
- `Debug="false"` in my `Sharepoint` `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, set your web.config Debug mode to false. This should already work.

If you wish to override the behaviour, put the following code in your OnPreRender method of your ASCX...

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    sm.ScriptMode = ScriptMode.Release;

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```